# Synchronous Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The new Universal Analytics re-introduces synchronous event tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#sync.

The documentation however is incomplete, it says:

> "This calling syntax will not work when loading the analytics.js
>   library using the default snippet. The default snippet is designed to
>   work with the asynchronous calling syntax."

So now I've only got a default (asynchronous) snippet:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-YY', 'mydomain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I can't find any mention of the correct snippet for synchronous calls. Anyone?

Answer (score 6):

Use this one:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script>    
    var tracker = ga.create('UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
    tracker.send('pageview');
  </script>
```

Tested.