# ReferenceError: ga is not defined on some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, google-analytics

I've got a Laravel 5 website, using Google Universal Analytics. On my cart page, I send a GA event via Javascript. However this causes a "ReferenceError: ga is not defined" on some browsers (e.g. IE, Chrome on Android, Windows 7, Mac OS). On other browsers it works just fine (e.g. Chrome & Firefox on Windows 10)

Making GA load synchronously seems to fix the issue on IE ([Synchronous Universal Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146182/synchronous-universal-analytics)) but I'm not sure if it will cover all browsers. In any case, is there a better way to solve this?

```
<head>
<script>

        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', '{{ getenv('GA') }}', 'auto');
        ga('set', 'userId', {{$ga_u_id}});
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        ga('require', 'ec');
    </script>
</head>
```

Then in Javascript (jQuery specifically) later in the body:

```
                    ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'cart', 'none', 50);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did u use document.ready?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski Yes, and everything else in that jQuery section works perfectly